# I'm having problems installing Visual studio 2017 offline

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm having a specific problem with Visual studio 2017 offline.
When i run the vs_community.exe or vs_professional.exe the initial installer window comes up. Clicking continue brings up 2 progress bars the top for verification and the bottom for installation.

The verification progress bar is immediately at 100%. and after about 2 mins, the window disappears, and nothing installs.

MS web pages aren't of very much help

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me, was that the target machines didn't have the correct version of .Net framework

from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/vs2017-system-requirements-vs

> .NET Framework 4.5 is required to install Visual Studio. Visual Studio requires .NET Framework 4.6.1, which will be installed during setup.

installing .NetFramework 4.7.1 solved the problem for me

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=56116